# With FlatBuffer full reflection get the underlying vector type?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Using the FlatBuffer full reflection

Relevant code

```cpp
const reflection::Schema& schema = *reflection::GetSchema( binary_fbs_file.c_str() );
auto root_table = schema.root_table();

auto fields = root_table->fields();

for (size_t = 0; i < fields->size(); i++)
{
    auto field = fields->Get( i );
    // 14 is the enum number for vector.
    if ( field->type()->base_type() == 14 )
    {
     // How do I check the type of the vector here?
    }
}
```

Relevant question in the code but how do I check what's the type of the vector? Is it an int32, double, string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field->type()->element()` Is the type of the vector contents.

See [reflection.fbs](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/0471fa807ccfb183acaac2ed9dd451a2782ea598/reflection/reflection.fbs#L35-L36) for details on `element`.